# Using a ui library with react native web

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native, react-native-web

i'm trying to use native base with react native web with out a lot of success, i tried looking for info if this is even possible but there doesn't seem to be a lot of info available.

I tried importing it but i get this error:

```
SyntaxError /node_modules/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view/lib/KeyboardAwareHOC.js: Unexpected token (14:12) native-base
```

Here is a conde sandbox with the error https://codesandbox.io/s/react-native-web-native-base-3cih6?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Can you please add more details on what you tried so far ?

Comment: To be honest i'm pretty new in the react wold, I tried following the steps in the "setup with web" part of the official docs https://docs.nativebase.io/docs/GetStarted.html, but i get the error posted above, when I tried looking for info it seems is trying to access a library not made for web so i'm kinda stuck.